# Angular form não pega valor digitado no input

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um problema onde o angular não está atribuindo valor a variável de um campo input meu.

Segue o código:

component.html

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center" id="formulario">
    <form class="form-inline" (submit)="findRegister(nameInput.value)">
      <input #nameInput type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Jane Doe">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../services/data.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  offset:number;
  registers:Register[];

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) { }

  findRegister(value){
    this.dataService.getRegisters(value, this.offset).subscribe(registers => {
      this.registers = registers.data;
      console.log(this.registers);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.offset=1;
    this.findRegister("Luiz");
  }
  incrementOffset(){
    this.offset++;
    this.findRegister("luiz");
  }
  decrementOffset(){
    this.offset--;
    this.findRegister("luiz");
  }

}
interface Register{
  id: string,
  name: string,
  username: string;
}
```

Fiz algumas chamadas a findRegister passando um string só pra testar o service, que tá funcionando tudo ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente trocar o `(submit)` por `(ngSubmit)`.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="formulario">
  <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="findRegister(nameInput.value)">
    <input #nameInput type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Jane Doe">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

### UPDATE

Sugiro você usar o `Template-Driven Form` pois as alterações serão minimas no seu código.

Você vai precisar:

- Importar `FormsModule` do `@angular/forms`
- Criar uma variável de template no seu `<form>` e atribuir o valor `ngForm` a ela. Ex: `<form #searchForm="ngForm">`
- Atribuir um nome ao seu input usando o atributo `name` e colocar a diretiva `ngModel` nele. Ex: `<input type="text" name="name" ngModel />`
- Então você passa por parâmetro ao método do submit `searchForm.value.name`. Ex: `<form #searchForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="findRegister(searchForm.value.name)">`

Exemplo:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="formulario">
  <form class="form-inline" #searchForm="ngForm (ngSubmit)="findRegister(searchForm.value.name)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" placeholder="Jane Doe" name="name" ngModel>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Já havia feito isso mas não obtive resultado.

Comment: Se bem que você está usando um formulário da maneira errada como é recomendado. Mais tarde chegando em casa coloco o código da maneira ideal para você usar.

Comment: @FabianoAmaral fiz uns testes aqui com seu código usando (submit) e (ngSubmit) e ambos estão funcionando normalmente. Você esta importando o FormsModule no módulo do seu componente?

Comment: Era o FormsModule!